# Angular Material Table filterPredicate to filter objects

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-table with a text input to filter it's results.

Datasource is:

```
[
    {
        "articolo": {
            "code": "22.398.14",
            "url": "/url1"
        },
        "color": "white",
        "weight": "10"
    },
    {
        "articolo": {
            "code": "22.398.15",
            "url": "/url2"
        },
        "color": "red",
        "weight": "20"
    }
]
```

I add this in html:

```
    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Filtra</mat-label>
    <input matInput (focus)="setupFilter('articolo')" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
```

And in ts:

```
setupFilter(column: string) {
    this.data.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
      data[column].code.indexOf(filter) != -1;
    }
  }

applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.data.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

But nothing happens

If I add a console.log inside filterPredicate it doesn't fire:

```
this.data.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
      console.log(data);
...
```

What's wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to make own filtering behaviour for your "code" attribute create it onese in constructor or ngOnInit hook, just like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
      return data.articolo.code.indexOf(filter) != -1;
    }
  }
```

Pay attention on return statement in filterPredicate. You don't used it!
Also, you don't need this (focus)="setupFilter('articolo')" .
all you have to do just call applyFilter, as you do it, like this:

```
applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    console.log(this.dataSource.filteredData);
  }
```

Then you can see in console your filtered data during changing input value.
Hope, I helped you .I can't understand why your data is nested. Good idea weel be first convert this data, then apply filters. May be in your case it's good.

Comment: you example it's just for a column...

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a function nevertheless not calling it.

`this.data.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
  data[column].code.indexOf(filter) != -1;
}`

`Try`

to console log this.data.filterPredicate(data, filter). This will return nothing, arrgggh you have a function that is not returning anything.

`Catch (e) =>`

```
do one thing at a time: so, a function. Console log direct.
```

Comment: chouette go go :)